# TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable - serializers.ListField()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this 2 models: Route and Order. Route has a relation oneToMany with Order as you can see:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='retailer')
    date_publish = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    date_available = models.DateField()
    weight = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route, related_name='orders', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Route(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField()
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    start_time = models.TimeField()
```

When a order is created it's route should be null. When a route is created I want to associate orders with the route created, so I have the following Route Serializer.

```
class routeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orders = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ['day', 'warehouse', 'start_time', 'orders']


    def create(self, validated_data):

        keys_to_extract = ['day', 'warehouse', 'start_time']
        route_subset = {key: validated_data[key] for key in keys_to_extract}

        print(validated_data)

        route = Route.objects.create(**route_subset)

        for order_data in validated_data['orders']:
            Order.objects.filter(id=order_data).update(route=route)

        return route
```

The body of the request should be like this:

```
{
    "day" : "2021-12-12",
    "warehouse": "1",
    "start_time": "7:00",
    "orders": [
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7
    ]
}
```

I was doing this in a different way, but I was told to do this in this way, but with orders = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(). But in that way I can't get the 'orders' from validated_data since it just come with 'day', 'warehouse' and 'start_time', so I tried to use serializers.ListField(). Now validated_data has the list of Orders primary keys and Order.objects.filter(id=order_data).update(route=route) updates the orders instances, but I get the error `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`
when I create a Route and when I try to list routes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:

```
class routeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orders = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=False, queryset=Order.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ['day', 'warehouse', 'start_time', 'orders']


    def create(self, validated_data):

        keys_to_extract = ['day', 'warehouse', 'start_time']
        route_subset = {key: validated_data[key] for key in keys_to_extract}
        
        route = Route.objects.create(**route_subset)

        for order_data in validated_data['orders']:
            Order.objects.filter(id=order_data.id).update(route=route)

        return route
```

I got back to `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but the query_set was missing before.